# How to get this attribute using linq to xml?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Result ID="1,New" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>
    <ID />
    <z:row ows_ID="6" />
</Result>
```

I have been trying to get the `ows_ID` value using the following methods:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
string newId = (from r in resDoc.Descendants(ns + "row")
               select (string)r.Attribute("ows_ID")).First();
```

which returns no records, and:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
string newId = (from r in resDoc.Descendants(ns + "z:row")
               select (string)r.Attribute("ows_ID")).First();
```

which throws an error from the `:`

What is the proper way for me to get this value?

**UPDATE - Complete `z:row` node**

```
<z:row ows_ContentTypeId="0x010090ADDB8ED990B741A07020AB204CDB880100311975766C6F0E4CBE4EBFBC3CBFD9AB" ows_Title="test 2 attachments343434" ows_AggregateDesc="&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClass05363FABD7BB400483A6AE4BB3B9B6CE&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;yes?&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" ows_Remarks="&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassB63AA0BFC1804E24B10C9559D7FBEBA5&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;no?&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" ows_PublishDate="2012-06-15 12:00:00" ows_MemoStatus="Submitted" ows_ID="6" ows_ContentType="FridayMemo" ows_Modified="2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_Created="2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_Author="49;#Abe Miessler" ows_Editor="49;#Abe Miessler" ows_owshiddenversion="1" ows_WorkflowVersion="1" ows__UIVersion="512" ows__UIVersionString="1.0" ows_Attachments="0" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows_LinkTitleNoMenu="test 2 attachments343434" ows_LinkTitle="test 2 attachments343434" ows_LinkTitle2="test 2 attachments343434" ows_SelectTitle="6" ows_Order="600.000000000000" ows_GUID="{393F36F5-FFA8-4F6E-A12A-1107AA713F25}" ows_FileRef="6;#nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo/6_.000" ows_FileDirRef="6;#nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo" ows_Last_x0020_Modified="6;#2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_Created_x0020_Date="6;#2012-06-27 14:00:47" ows_FSObjType="6;#0" ows_SortBehavior="6;#0" ows_PermMask="0x7fffffffffffffff" ows_FileLeafRef="6;#6_.000" ows_UniqueId="6;#{F4C6B345-4590-4791-9384-18983132F055}" ows_ProgId="6;#" ows_ScopeId="6;#{8450C4BD-0866-40ED-A0CD-22E3105E0845}" ows__EditMenuTableStart="6_.000" ows__EditMenuTableStart2="6" ows__EditMenuTableEnd="6" ows_LinkFilenameNoMenu="6_.000" ows_LinkFilename="6_.000" ows_LinkFilename2="6_.000" ows_ServerUrl="/nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo/6_.000" ows_EncodedAbsUrl="http://sptestmnc.nevcounty.net/nc/ceo/Lists/FridayMemo/6_.000" ows_BaseName="6_" ows_MetaInfo="6;#" ows__Level="1" ows__IsCurrentVersion="1" ows_ItemChildCount="6;#0" ows_FolderChildCount="6;#0" 
  xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
```

Comment: Your XML uses the "z" namespace alias - but doesn't define it. Is that the *complete* document?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I had trimmed my `z:row` node down to what I cared about, so that is not the complete XML.  I have included the complete `z:row` node in my update, but I don't see where another namespace would be referenced.

Comment: It's not the z row itself which is important - it's which *namespace* it's in. There's nothing in the XML you've shown which defines what `z` means as a namespace alias.

Comment: If you take into account the updated `z:row` in my update, the xml I have shown is exactly as it was displayed to me when I viewed it through my XDocument object.  I understand that there is a missing namespace, but this is the xml that was returned from a call to a SharePoint web service.  Is there somewhere else I should be looking for it?

Comment: So there's *really* no `xmlns:z="..."` anywhere in the document? Eek. I'm surprised that's valid at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet, actually it looks like there was at the very end of my updated `z:row` element.  DarkGray was able to find that hidden in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var ns = XNamespace.Get("#RowsetSchema");
    var id = xml
      .Descendants(ns + "row")
      .Select(row => row.Attribute("ows_ID").Value)
      .First();
```

or

```
    var ns = XNamespace.Get("#RowsetSchema");
    var id = xml
      .Descendants(ns + "row")
      .First()
      .Attribute("ows_ID")
      .Value;
```

Comment: So am I supposed to put `#RowsetSchema` in there or is that a place holder for something?

Comment: @AbeMiessler put #RowsetSchema

Comment: Thank you so much!  Can you explain what that does?

Comment: @AbeMiessler I read your xml example accuratelly. Row element contains namespace description in end: xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema".

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying the namespace correctly for the `Descendants` method.  It takes an `XName` (which offers an implicit cast from string, fooling you into thinking it takes a string).  You can use the `Get(string,string)` static method of `XName` to specify the namespace:

```
string ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
string newId = (from r in resDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("row",ns))
    select (string)r.Attribute("ows_ID")).First();
```

Per the OP's request, here is the complete sample code I wrote, that compiles and works correctly in LINQPad:

```
var ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
var xml = 
    @"<Result ID=""1,New"" xmlns=""" + ns + @""">" +
        @"<ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode>" +
        @"<ID />" +
        @"<z:row ows_ID=""6"" />" +
    @"</Result>";

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
mgr.AddNamespace("z", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/");
XmlParserContext ctx = new XmlParserContext(null, mgr, null, XmlSpace.Default);
XDocument resDoc;
using( XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), null, ctx) ) {
    resDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}

string newId = (from r in resDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("row",ns))
    select (string)r.Attribute("ows_ID")).First();

Console.WriteLine( newId );     // prints "6"
```

Comment: Interesting, I've seen the namespace specified that way in Descendants before, and use it successfully in the past (as long as the namespace was defined in the XML).  Either way, I tried  what you have above and it wouldn't compile.  I then switched it to `XName.Get("row","z")` and no records were found.  Did I do something incorrectly here?

Comment: Hm, not that I'm aware of, Abe.  I compiled your example (with my edit), and it was able to pull out the `ows_ID` field correctly....  I'm at a loss now as to why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Oh, I just saw one problem; `XName.Get` takes two *strings*, not a stirng and an `XNamespace`.  Try specifying `ns` as a string, not an `XNamespace` (answer corrected above).

Comment: Very strange.  Could you include all of the code from your working example? Maybe I missed something on my end.

Comment: I posted the complete sample program I wrote.

Comment: @EthanBrown Abe Miessler's xml example is another. Row element namespace is xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the 'z' namespace which must be defined somewhere not shown in this code to access that element, the one that you are using is the one you are setting for your root element.